# getting an error whenever i am giving the command "nodemon app.js" in terminal ,app.js is a api file in my folder

Tags: node.js

whenever i am giving command in terminal : nodemon app.js, it shows this error.app.js is my api file.

nodemon : File C:\Users\DAS27\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.ps1 cannot be loaded
because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see
about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- nodemon app
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

Comment: Did the documentation link the error message gave you not help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.